# Laravel nova v3.12 after user authenticated is giving 403 Forbidden

Tags: http-status-code-403, laravel-nova

I have cloned a project on same server...

App1: **tekmab.com.br**
Folder: **/home/tekmab/webapps/tekmab**

App2: **demo.tekmab.com.br**
Folder: **/home/demo/webapps/tekmab-demo**

App2 is for test purposes before send it to production (app1)

App2 is working fine. But app1, works only until nova auth page. After user auth, it redirects to the default 403 page.

Looking on server logs, don't have any line about this recent 403.

So, I don't know what to do next.

I'm using `Laravel 7` and `nova v3.12` with nginx

Everything works outside nova... and with nova until the auth page. Just go to 403 with authenticated users. And this does not generate any 403 entry on the server logs (or any other entry)

Comment: Check if project has some policies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order for it to work in production, you need to add your email in the gate method at NovaServiceProvider

after that try to clear config.
it should work.